# "Open Selection in Microsoft Excel" option missing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am trying to export the Code Metrics Results in Visual Studio 2019 to Excel, but I am not seeing the option, "Open Selection in Microsoft Excel", in the context menu. How to enable that option?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the Excel option either by right clicking on one of the items in the list, or by exporting the entire list using the Excel button in the top ribbon:

[image]

If you have the window for the code metrics condensed, you may need to click the double arrows (►►) in the top right to open the menu, which should contain the Excel export button:

[image]